# Timer Doesn't Count In Background Tab

Tags: javascript, timer

I have this timer:

```
$scope.startTimer = function(homework) {
    homework.Timer = function() {
        if(homework.timer) {
            homework.estimatedTime.spentNow++;
            homework.calcTimes()
            $scope.$apply();
            window.setTimeout(homework.Timer, 1000);
        }
    }
    homework.timer = true;
    window.setTimeout(homework.Timer, 1000);
}
$scope.stopTimer = function(homework) {
    homework.timer = false;
    homework.stoppingTimer = true;
    homework.save().then(function() {
        homework.stoppingTimer = false;
    })
}
```

Which works, except when in a background tab (at least in Safari)

How can I make this timer work, even in the background?

Comment: on window's blur get the currentTime or performance.now, then on window's focus get the difference with the new currentTime or performance.now

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: Looks like it... I searched everywhere but couldn't find that. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't help you to solve your problem, but, why don't you use timeout in Angular way? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Comment: Didn't know about that.